# Algorithm to match URLs from a pool

Tags: regex, algorithm, computer-science, graph-theory

This title is horrendous.

I'm not sure how to quickly describe this problem. I'm a self taught programmer (hobby > 10 yrs, professional > 3yrs) so I don't have a lot of the computer science knowledge that would help with a problem like this, which is why I'm posting this up. I'm hoping to hear of better ways to solve this problem. I don't need a blown out solution, but instead maybe some type of data structure or algorithm that could help me. A bump in the right direction.

I have URLs that are built from states, eg:

```
state: 'foo', url: '/foo'
state: 'foo.bar' url: '/bar'
```

`foo`'s url is `/foo` and

`bar`'s url is `/foo/bar`

Does that make sense? It inherits the parent's URL.

Additionally, `bar` is a child of `foo` and a state can have unlimited number of children: `foo.bar`, `foo.zar`, `foo.far`, `etc.` and children can have children, `foo.bar.alpha`, `foo.bar.beta`, `etc`. This has no strict max depth.

So, URL crafting is the easy part, it's been done. I'm trying to do the reverse.

If I have the url `/foo/bar`, how do I go about finding what state created this url?

The issue is that a state's URL can be as long as it likes and doesn't have to start uniquely, eg:

```
state: 'zar', url: '/one/two/three'
state: 'far', url: '/one/two/nine'
```

One solution I've come up with is make a lookup table with all created URLs that point to the state that created them. It wouldn't be horrible to create, but doesn't seem very smart, it feels very brute-force.

My second solution is to split the url to be analyzed into chunks, splitting by slash `/`, then analyzing each "root" state by splitting that URL by `/` as well, and match as many blocks as I can, then selecting the one that has the most matched blocks. My problem here is that I could end up going down the wrong path:

```
state: 'alpha', url: '/alpha'
state: 'alpha.beta', url: '/beta'
state: 'alpha.beta.gamma', url: '/gamma'

state: 'foxtrot', url: '/alpha'
state: 'foxtrot.beta', url: '/beta'
state: 'foxtrot.beta.gamma', url: '/foxy'
```

Where there is a potential to pick `alpha` > `alpha.beta` then fail because there is no `/foxy` state, where the correct root was `foxtrot`. It also seems this way could be slower, having to build URLs on the fly instead of using a lookup. Additionally, a specific case like this would be very odd indeed, but could happen.

I appreciate anyone who may even give this a look over. If anyone cares, I'll be implementing a lookup table to solve this in the interim, but I'm very curious about other solutions.

**Edit:**

Here's something you can play with if interested: https://jsbin.com/muvuza/4/edit?js,console

Comment: Is this javascript?

Comment: Is state a generic JS object? Any more info on what exactly a state is? Why do zar and far have the same URL but different states?

Comment: Yes this is technically javascript, but I'm not explicitly looking for a JS specific answer.

The zar and far examples are extremes. I don't have anything that does that currently but it would technically be possible. 

State is a generic JS object where each key is a state, also child states. So you could do state['foo'] or state['foo.bar'], which would return an object. This object has reference to `parent` (if any) and array of `children` (Again, if any).

Comment: In any given language you'd need a lookup table to match the url string pieces to a generic object. In JS you can access properties on an object directly with a string, so the lookup table is basically done for you. Check out my answer

Comment: This is probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Agreed. Anyway to port it over?

Answer (score 0):

You want to map a string to an object. As far as I know you'll need a lookup table to do this in any given language. In JS you can access an object's properties directly using a string, so this table is basically already done for you.

```
//javascript
//define some states
var starting_states = [zar, far, alpha, foxtrot];
var url = '/zar/one/two/three/';
var urlPieces = url.split("/");

//Iterate through states, selecting the next hashed object
var state = starting_states[urlPieces[0]];
for(var i=1;i<urlPieces.length;i++){
  state = state[ urlPieces[i] ];
}
```

Comment: I've added a jsbin to the original post if you'd like to look at it.

Comment: Why don't you just nest those states within one another? That would be much cleaner. And if the state's only property is url, which is just the name of the state + '/', it would make much more sense to just make a function to turn strings into urls.

Comment: I do nest states, granted not as cleanly as alpha.beta. If you look at the bottom, I take the defined states and nest them by `parent` and `children` properties. In the actual implementation there are many more properties to a state than just 'url'.

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept and upvote.